# API client, using an injectable helper to aid testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection

**description**

> write a api client that fetch items from remote service
>
> I have separated `Service{}` class's helper methods into another class
>   `serviceHelper{}` and made it injectable to `Service{}` class.
>
> With this approach I think I get these benefits
>
> - I can mocking `serviceHelper{}` class
> - When I mock the `serviceHelper{}` class then I easily testing the `Service{}` class.

**client.go**

```
// Media Types
const (
    ApplicationForm = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
)

// Client interface
type Client interface {
    Do(*http.Request, interface{}) (*http.Response, error)
}

type serviceHelperer interface {
    createSearchRequest(*search.CoralSearchRequest) (*http.Request, error)
    toAPIError(error, int) error
}

// Service service
type Service struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    client   Client
    h        serviceHelperer
}

type serviceHelper struct {
}

// New instances new coral service
func New(username string, password string, c Client) *Service {
    return &Service{username, password, c, &serviceHelper{}}
}

func (h *serviceHelper) toAPIError(err error, status int) error {
    if err == nil {
        return err
    }
    if status > 399 || status < 200 {
        var apiErr domain.CoralAPIError
        if err2 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(err.Error()), &apiErr); err2 != nil {
            return err
        }
        return apiErr
    }
    return err
}

const defaultCurrency = "TRY"
const defaultNationality = "TR"

// createSearchRequest creates search request
func (h *serviceHelper) createSearchRequest(r *search.CoralSearchRequest) (*http.Request, error) {
    // send hotel_codes field as post request instead of get,
    // beacause of hotel_codes there can be thousands (url too long error)
    var body io.Reader
    if len(r.HotelCodes) > 0 {
        form := url.Values{"hotel_code": r.HotelCodes}
        body = strings.NewReader(form.Encode())
    }

    query := url.Values{
        "pax":                r.Pax,
        "checkin":            []string{r.Checkin},
        "checkout":           []string{r.Checkout},
        "client_nationality": []string{defaultNationality},
        "currency":           []string{defaultCurrency},
        "destination_code":   []string{r.DestinationCode},
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "search?"+query.Encode(), body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", ApplicationForm)
    return req, nil
}

// Search makes search request to coral.
func (s *Service) Search(r *search.CoralSearchRequest) (*search.CoralSearchResponse, error) {
    req, err := s.h.createSearchRequest(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(s.Username, s.Password)

    var sr search.CoralSearchResponse

    res, err := s.client.Do(req, &sr)

    err = s.h.toAPIError(err, res.StatusCode)

    return &sr, err
}
```

**mock_test.go** contains mock classes

```
// this file contains mocks shared with this package

type serviceHelperMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

type clientMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (sm *serviceHelperMock) createSearchRequest(r *search.CoralSearchRequest) (*http.Request, error) {
    args := sm.Mock.Called(r)
    return args.Get(0).(*http.Request), args.Error(1)
}

func (sm *serviceHelperMock) toAPIError(err error, status int) error {
    args := sm.Mock.Called(err, status)
    return args.Error(0)
}

func (m *clientMock) Do(r *http.Request, v interface{}) (*http.Response, error) {
    args := m.Mock.Called(r, v)
    return args.Get(0).(*http.Response), args.Error(1)
}
```

**client_test.go** contains tests

```
var baseURL = &url.URL{
    Scheme: "https",
    Host:   "example.com",
    Path:   "/",
}

func TestService_Search(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    client := &clientMock{}
    helper := &serviceHelperMock{}
    service := Service{"", "", client, helper}

    coralSearchReq := &search.CoralSearchRequest{Pax: []string{"1"}}
    coralSearchRes := &search.CoralSearchResponse{}
    searchRes := &http.Response{StatusCode: http.StatusOK}

    helper.On("createSearchRequest", coralSearchReq).Return(&http.Request{}, nil).Once()
    client.On("Do", mock.Anything, coralSearchRes).Return(searchRes, nil).Once()
    helper.On("toAPIError", nil, searchRes.StatusCode).Return(nil).Once()

    actualCoralSearchRes, err := service.Search(coralSearchReq)

    helper.AssertExpectations(t)
    client.AssertExpectations(t)

    ensure.Nil(t, err)
    ensure.DeepEqual(t, actualCoralSearchRes, coralSearchRes)

    t.Run("should stop execution when createSearchRequest() return an error", func(t *testing.T) {
        client := &clientMock{}
        helper := &serviceHelperMock{}
        service := Service{"", "", client, helper}

        err := errors.New("unexpected")
        helper.On("createSearchRequest", coralSearchReq).Return(&http.Request{}, err).Once()

        _, actualErr := service.Search(coralSearchReq)

        helper.AssertExpectations(t)

        ensure.DeepEqual(t, actualErr, err)
    })
}

func Test_serviceHelper_createSearchRequest(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    var pax = []string{"2,1", "3,1"}
    var checkin = "2018-06-20"
    var checkout = "2018-06-30"
    var hotelCodes = []string{"code1", "code2"}
    var destinationCode = ""
    var nationality = "TR"
    var currency = "TRY"

    query := url.Values{
        "pax":                pax,
        "checkin":            []string{checkin},
        "checkout":           []string{checkout},
        "destination_code":   []string{destinationCode},
        "client_nationality": []string{nationality},
        "currency":           []string{currency},
    }

    body := ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(url.Values{"hotel_code": hotelCodes}.Encode()))

    sh := &serviceHelper{}

    r, err := sh.createSearchRequest(&search.CoralSearchRequest{
        Pax:        pax,
        Checkin:    checkin,
        Checkout:   checkout,
        HotelCodes: hotelCodes,
    })

    ensure.Nil(t, err)

    ensure.DeepEqual(t, r.Method, "POST")
    ensure.DeepEqual(t, r.URL.String(), "search?"+query.Encode())
    ensure.DeepEqual(t, r.Header.Get("Content-Type"), ApplicationForm)
    ensure.DeepEqual(t, r.Body, body)
    // todo: test basic auth header?
}
```

**Questions**

- is this method correct?
- is there better way than that?
- do you have a better name than `serviceHelper` (*Helper?)

Comment: I find your use of the word class disturbing ;-P. You're trying to use patterns/approaches that don't map terribly to golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to change a little bit how you use the interfaces.

Since `createSearchRequest` and `toAPIError` don't have external dependencies, I would attach them directly to your `Service` (and remove `serviceHelper`)

Since the `Client` is already an interface, you are already able mock it (to prevent performing a real http request and return errors with special statuses).

However you could turn your `Service` into an interface:

```
type Searcher interface {
    Search(*search.CoralSearchRequest) (*search.CoralSearchResponse, error)
}
```

It would greatly ease the testing of packages depending on this `Service`

Comment: in this case how would test error case of createSearchRequest?

Comment: That's a good point. Actually it should never fail: [`http.NewRequest`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=25278:25347#L759) returns an error if: the method is not valid ("POST" is valid) / if the `url` is not parsable ("search?"+query.Encode() is parsable) / if the `io.Reader` returns an error, which won't be the case.

Comment: But if you really want to test this case, then you could provide add a `NewRequest` property to the `Service` struct and initialize it with `http.NewRequest` (or some other mock to trigger the error)